# Does Readdle (Spark) keep my logins/passwords on their own servers?

Tags: passwords, email

I have installed Spark application (mail application from Readdle) on my Mac and found out suspicious logins from California in the logs of my mail server.

[image]

I am in Russia and don't use this application's password in any other applications. I have checked the IP addresses (104.196.115.172, 104.196.189.179, 104.197.31.95, 104.196.161.60) - it looks like Google Cloud.

I have created a new mail account on the different mail server and checked mail from Spark application. The same story: after 20-24 hours I have found logins from the USA:

[image]

I have created a request on Readdle support, but didn't receive any answer after 2 days.

I am not security expert, but it looks very queerly. First of all, Readdle keeps my login and password on their own servers. Second, they periodically connect to my mail account using my login and password.

What do you think about it?  Do I need to worry or is it OK?

Comment: did you connect to cloud storage when you set it up?

Comment: @schroeder, which one ? I don't use google cloud, but I am connect to iCloud. But I set up password and login to Spark program, not iCloud interface.

Comment: Spark has a feature where you can connect it to cloud storage. That is what I meant.

Comment: @schroeder No, I have checked. I have option "Sync settings with iCloud" turned off.

Comment: Lots of apps do this now, including Microsoft Outlook for iOS. They usually don't tell you when you set up your account, so I tend to stay away from 3rd party email clients now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reply from support:

> We use server side pushes to send you fast notifications. In order to
>   send these push notifications, Spark server needs to check your email
>   account — either using Oauth token (for Google, Outlook and yahoo
>   account) or via your credentials. Our servers are located in the US,
>   so probably yes, these are connections from our servers.

I would preferer to have an option to turn off this notifications. Now I have changed the email client.